# Electron: TouchBarButton click callback wrong parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, electron, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm currently working on integrating [**MacBook TouchBar**](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/touch-bar) on a basic **Electron Project** (like a Hello World :p ).

My project is very simple: I had an **array** of String which represent each a **Directory name**, I want to create a `TouchBarButton` **for each item** in the array.

But I'm facing a problem with the `TouchBarButton` **click callback**: when I touch a Button it **always** return me **the last object** from my array (*items2* in my case) even if I click the first one!

*Note*: it works very well for the icon !

```
var dirs = ['item1', 'items2']
var barItems = [ ];

for(var i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) {
  var aDir = dirs[i]
  var button = new TouchBarButton({
    icon: `${aDir}/icon.png`,
    click: () => {
      console.log(`Dir ${aDir}`) // Always return me Dir items2 even if I select the first one in the Touch Bar...
    },
  })

  barItems.push(button)
}

return new TouchBar({
  items: barItems,
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !